# How to compile and run java program in nokia c6-00?

Tags: java, nokia

I have ***nokia c6***. I can compile and run the c and c++ codes with dos-box. But how to do same things with ***java***, Is it possible ?? Is there any other way to run ***java program in nokia c6-00***. Plz help me.
Thanx in advance.  :)

Comment: I don't know of any reasonably functional JVM implementation for Symbian phones.  (Though in many ways Qt is functionally equivalent to Java and in some instances superior, and it is an easy transliteration from Java in many cases.)

Comment: Maybe there are some jvm emulators :)

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık -- Yeah, but they probably only run on the simulator. ;)

Comment: If symbian derived from C/C++, we could write jvm from ground at least only for some methods :) But we need a un-obfuscator and some comp. + soft. eng. friends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create Java programs for Nokia C6. Nokia C6 supports Java ME.